# How to get request object printed on browser console instead of terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to node.js and I am trying to find a way to get **request** object printed on browser's console instead of terminal, I use chrome.

```
var app = express();

app.post("/campgrounds", function(request, response) {
    console.log(req);
    res.send("POST");
});
```

How can I print request in browser's console?

The reason is that output on browser is more user-friendly and hence easier to inspect.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't really do what you're asking. The workaround is that if you're on a version of node > 7, you can run your code with `node --inspect`, and it'll spit out a URL you can paste into chrome and use to debug your code.

Comment: Server side responses will be shown in terminal while client side responses on browser console. I think it's better to keep it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly print anything on the browser.

What you can do is either:

1. Send what you want printed in the response to the request and add some client-side code that would print it for all responses. You will only be able to print something once per request.
2. Use WebSocket or Socket.io to create a connection used only for the message printing. You need both server-side and client-side code for that but it would not be very complex. You will be able to print anything any time.

If you want 2 then see my project on GitHub that changes the website color and change the color changing code to `console.log()` to print whatever was received on the socket. Of course you will need to make sure that you only print it on the browser that made the request if that is your intention.

The project that you can start from:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-live-color

Comment: Thank you sir, I think I will go with number 2